# Facebook graph api get all post (group) include author use one token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

{groupid}/feed?**fields=from**. 
How do I get the authors of the posts using one of my tokens. According to the documentation, the user must give me permission to do this and get into the list of participants (opted_in_members).
How to request permission from another user?

I am logged in my site to another user with permissions
publish_to_groups
groups_access_member_info
public_profile

but the username never made it to the opted_in_members list and I still don't get it as an author

What should my group member do so that I can see him an author in "from" field,

I would like to instruct members of my group, but i don't understand how to do it.
the guide has no information about it.

Comment: They need to login to the same app that you are using, and grant it the necessary permission ...

Comment: @CBroe With another account (group member) I tried to log in using my app the 3 permissions indicated above, but he was not included in the opted_in_members list

Comment: Do you get _any_ users on that list? Your app would have to be "installed" in the group, is that the case?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, the application is installed by me in the group. I'm the only one in the opted_in_members list. I get myself as the author of a post if this is my post, but I don't get the authors of other posts

Comment: Can you verify that the other user _has_ granted the `groups_access_member_info` permission? (Request `me/permissions/groups_access_member_info` using that account's access token, or verify via the Facebook UI.)